Solving recurrence relation $T(n) = \max\{T(k)+T(n−k)+O(\min\{k, n-k\})\}$
My question arises out of this competitive programming problem. The idea is to find a unique element $u$ and then divide-and-conquer for the subarray to the left and to the right of $u$.
Searching for the unique element naïvely in a single forward pass leads to an $O(n^2)$ algorithm. However, if we search from both ends simultaneously, we would have a recurrence relation shown in the title. Notably, it avoid the worst case scenario in the naïve algorithm. Does this improve the asymptotic time complexity?

It gives $T(n) = O(n \log n)$. Let's prove by induction that $T(n) \le Cn \log n$, for some big enough $C \in \mathbb{R}$:
The induction hypothesis is that $T(n) \le C n \log n$. Now take $T(1) = 0$ as the base case, notice that any $C$ satisfies the hypothesis. Now let's prove it for some $n > 1$, assuming the hypothesis is true for all $1 \le k < n$:
\begin{align*}
(1) \quad T(n) &= \max_{1 \le k < n}\{T(k) + T(n-k) + O(\min(k, n-k))\} \\
(2) \quad T(n) &= \max_{1 \le k \le \frac{n}{2}}\{T(k) + T(n-k) + O(k)\}, \hspace{.5em} \text{by symmetry on k}\\
(3) \quad T(n) &\le \max_{1 \le k \le \frac{n}{2}}\{T(k) + T(n-k) + c k\} , \hspace{.5em} \text{for some } c \in \mathbb{R}\\
(4) \quad T(n) &\le \max_{1 \le k \le \frac{n}{2}}\{Ck \log k + C(n-k) \log (n-k) + ck\} \\
(5) \quad T(n) &\le C n \log n, \hspace{.5em} \text{for big enough }C
\end{align*}
And we have our proof by induction. Intuition in step $(4) \to (5)$, is that the function $x \log x + (n - x) \log (n-x)$ in $[1, n-1]$ is symmetric and convex ($x \log x$ is convex) maximizing at both ends, and choosing $k=1$ should maximize overall.
In order to prove $(4) \to (5)$, we want to show that
$$C n \log n \ge C x \log x + C (n-x) \log (n-x) + cx \quad \forall x \in \left[1, \frac{n}{2}\right]$$
when $C$ is big enough. We do the following:
$$ (C n \log n) - (C x \log x + C (n-x) \log (n-x) + cx) = $$
$$ = (C x \log n + C (n-x) \log n) - (C x \log x + C (n-x) \log (n-x) + cx) =$$
$$ = Cx(\log n - \log x) + C(n-x)(\log n - log (n-x)) - cx = $$
$$ = Cx\left(\log \frac{n}{x}\right) + C(n-x)\left(\log \frac{n}{n-x}\right) - cx \ge $$
$$ \ge Cx\log(2) - cx \ge 0, \hspace{.5em} \text{ when } C \gg c$$

Well, you need to give a fixed $C$ from the start. And I don't see how you do that with your current argument - if you replace $O(\min(k, n-k))$ in your argument with $O(n)$, your "proof" doesn't seem affected.

@Elucidase My fault! I guess now it's somehow correct.

Why does $k=1$ maximizes $(4)$? Seems false to me: when $k=1$ for every $n$ we get $O(n)$ but when $k=n/2$ for every $n$ we get $O(n\log n)$.

@Elucidase I added a proof for that, if I am not mistaken.

@Elucidase Also note that this does not imply on the real choice of $k$, since I am assuming that $T(n)$ is behaving as ~$n \log n$, and in this case, choosing $k=1$ seems to be the maximizing option. Note that $x \log x + (n-x) \log (n-x) + x$ has a minimum at $x=n/(1+e)$.

Assuming $O(k)$ in $(2)$ is bounded starting from $k=1$, I think this works.
